# Sort 2 Numbers in ArrayList Using C#?

Tags: sorting, arraylist

I am using an ArrayList to store objects of the class called SocialTimes. SocialTimes holds a string and 2 numbers. I'm trying to sort based on the Hour and Minute. I have no clue of how to do it. Can someone help me?

```
public class SocialTimes
{
    string DateToPostStr = "";
    int HourToPost = 0;
    int MinuteToPost = 0;

    public SocialTimes(string DateToPostStr, int HourToPost, int MinuteToPost)
    {
        this.DateToPostStr = DateToPostStr;
        this.HourToPost = HourToPost;
        this.MinuteToPost = MinuteToPost;
    }

    public string getDateToPostStr()
    {
        return this.DateToPostStr;
    }

    public int getHourToPost()
    {
        return this.HourToPost;
    }

    public int getMinuteToPost()
    {
        return this.MinuteToPost;
    }

    public static implicit operator SocialTimes(ArrayList v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public class myComparer : IComparer
{
    int IComparer.Compare(Object xx, Object yy)
    {
        SocialTimes x = (SocialTimes)xx;
        SocialTimes y = (SocialTimes)yy;
        return x.getHourToPost().CompareTo(y.getHourToPost());
    }
}
```

So here is a method to test the sort ArrayList...

```
    private void testHourMinuteSort()
    {
        ArrayList projects = new ArrayList();
        projects.Add(new SocialTimes("03/14/20", 17, 7));
        projects.Add(new SocialTimes("03/14/20", 10, 39));
        projects.Add(new SocialTimes("03/14/20", 12, 7));
        projects.Add(new SocialTimes("03/14/20", 3, 16));
        projects.Add(new SocialTimes("03/14/20", 21, 8));
        projects.Add(new SocialTimes("03/14/20", 20, 56));
        projects.Add(new SocialTimes("03/14/20", 3, 2));
        projects.Sort(new myComparer());
        string hoursminutes = "";

        foreach (SocialTimes item in projects)
        {
            hoursminutes = hoursminutes + String.Format("Hour: {0} Minute: {1}", item.getHourToPost(), item.getMinuteToPost()) + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(hoursminutes);
    }
```

hoursminutes:

- Hour: 3 Minute: 16
- Hour: 3 Minute: 2
- Hour: 10 Minute: 39
- Hour: 12 Minute: 7
- Hour: 17 Minute: 7
- Hour: 20 Minute: 56
- Hour: 21 Minute: 8

I need the sort to sort by hours and minutes like below.

- Hour: 3 Minute: 2
- Hour: 3 Minute: 16
- Hour: 10 Minute: 39
- Hour: 12 Minute: 7
- Hour: 17 Minute: 7
- Hour: 20 Minute: 56
- Hour: 21 Minute: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the values to minutes and compare, not just hours.

```
int x1 = t1.Hours * 60 + t1.Minutes;
```

As it is now, times with the same number of (whole) hours will be sorted “randomly” with respect to each other because the minutes are not compared.

Alternatively, just use LINQ and something like:

```
s.OrderBy(x => x.Hours).ThenBy(x => x.Minutes)
```

It would probably also be more clear to use a a Date and/or TimeSpan which represents dates and/or ranges of time well. In that case the above code would be simplified as only one value would be compared.

Using a proper generic collection type such as List<SocialTimes> is also a much more modern and type-safe way to deal with collections.

Comment: Thanks SO much. That worked perfectly. I added a method in the SocialTimes class. and used it in the class myComparer and works like a charm.

        public int getHourMinuteToPost()
        {
            int sum;

            sum = HourToPost * 60 + MinuteToPost;

            return sum;
        }